# How to vertically align the content inside flex items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox header that contains two child flex items. These flex items in turn have their own children.

Is there a way to override the vertical alignment of the flex items so that their children are aligned at the bottom?

```css
div.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch; /* cross axis */
  justify-content: space-between; /* main axis */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.item-1, .item-2 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.item-2 {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item-1">
    <span>I want to be aligned at the bottom of item-1</span>
  </div>

  <div class="item-2">
    <span>I want to be aligned at the bottom of item-2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  webkit-align-items to m

```
-webkit-align-items:flex-end;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5N2km/1/

Comment: I can't do that in this case, because I want the flex items to stretch: http://jsfiddle.net/5N2km/2/. What I want is to have the children of flex items to align at the bottom. Maybe I should make item-1 and item-2 flexboxes as well, and then apply align-items flex-end on them, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5N2km/3/?

Comment: Yes, make items also flexbox and apply 'align-items' will work, as you showed in this  http://jsfiddle.net/5N2km/3

Answer (score 2):

You can switch the value of `align-items` on the container from `stretch` to `flex-end`. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

```css
div.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;  /* adjusted */
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item-1, .item-2 {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.item-2 {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item-1">
    <span>I want to be aligned at the bottom of item-1</span>
  </div>

  <div class="item-2">
    <span>I want to be aligned at the bottom of item-2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But since your actual question is:

> Is there a way to override the vertical alignment of the flex items *so that their children are aligned at the bottom*?

... then you should make the flex items into nested flex containers and vertically align the content with flex properties:

```css
div.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item-1, .item-2 {
  display: flex;          /* new */
  align-items: flex-end;  /* new */
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.item-2 {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item-1">
    <span>I want to be aligned at the bottom of item-1</span>
  </div>

  <div class="item-2">
    <span>I want to be aligned at the bottom of item-2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```