# Make flex items stretch full height and vertically center their content

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a horizontal flex box (i.e. `flex-direction: row`, i.e. side-by-side) with a few items. Each item can be a single line of text, or can have multiple lines. I want to vertically-align the contents of each flex item.

If each item had a transparent background, I could easily use `align-items: center`. However, I want each item to be stretched vertically, because I want to set a background (or maybe borders, or maybe it is a clickable region) to the entire available height.

So far, I know:

- Stretching: `align-items: stretch`
- Aligning: `align-items: center`
- Stretching and aligning: ???

Demo available at http://codepen.io/denilsonsa/pen/bVBQNa

[image: Screenshot of the demo]

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
ul.first {
  align-items: stretch;
}
ul.second {
  align-items: center;
}
ul > li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}
ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #CFC;
}

/* Visual styles, just ignore. */
html, body { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 25px; }
ul, li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul { background: #CCF; width: 25em; }
```

```html
<ul class="first">
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li><span>span</span></li>
  <li><span>multiple</span> <span>span</span></li>
  <li>text <span>span</span></li>
  <li>multi<br>line</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul class="second">
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li><span>span</span></li>
  <li><span>multiple</span> <span>span</span></li>
  <li>text <span>span</span></li>
  <li>multi<br>line</li>
</ul>
```

---

Similar questions:

- [Question 14012030](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012030/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-vertical-align-of-items-inside-flex-items) and [question 23442692](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442692/css-flex-box-how-to-vertically-align-flex-items-to-middle-without-losing-flex) and [question 27729619](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729619/vertically-centring-text-inside-flexbox-item) and [question 25311541](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311541/vertically-aligning-text-inside-a-flexbox-without-an-additional-wrapper-element) ask essentially the same thing, but they either have a single element or plain text as child of each flex item. As soon as we have mixed content, possibly with multiple elements, those solutions do not work.
- [Question 19026884](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically) is unrelated, the issue there was the wrong markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to achieve the desired effect while using the exact markup posted in the question.

The solution involves:

- Setting `display: flex;` on `<li>`.
- Wrapping the `<li>` contents into another element.

  - This is required because `<li>` is now a flex container, so we need another element to prevent the actual contents from becoming flex items.
  - In this solution, I introduced a `<div>` element, but it could have been other element.
- Now that `<li>` is a flex container and it contains only a single child, we can use `align-items` and/or `justify-content` to align this new and only child.

The DOM tree looks like this:

```
<ul> flex-parent, direction=row
 ├ <li> flex-item && flex-parent && background && JavaScript clickable area
 │  └ <div> flex-item as a single transparent element
 │     ├ Actual contents
 │     └ Actual contents
 ├ …
```

**Note:** The solution in this answer uses 2 nested flex boxes. [The solution by Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32828900/) uses 3 nested flex boxes, because it has the added challenge of expanding the `<a>` element to fill the entire `<li>`. Which one is preferred depends on each case. If I could, I would accept both answers.

```css
/* New code: this is the solution. */
ul > li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Old code below. */
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
ul > li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}
ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #CFC;
}

/* Visual styles, just ignore. */
html, body { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 25px; }
ul, li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul { background: #CCF; width: 25em; }

button:focus + ul {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<button>Click here to set <code>width: auto</code> and reduce the font size.</button>

<!-- New code: there is a single <div> between each <li> and their contents. -->
<ul>
  <li><div>Sample</div></li>
  <li><div><span>span</span></div></li>
  <li><div><span>multiple</span> <span>span</span></div></li>
  <li><div>text <span>span</span></div></li>
  <li><div>multi<br>line</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

> I want each item to be stretched vertically, because I want to set a
>   background (or maybe borders, or maybe it is a clickable region) to
>   the entire available height.

You can achieve this layout without any changes to your HTML structure. There's no need for additional containers.

You already have a primary flex container and a group of flex items. Simply make those flex items into nested flex containers. That will enable you to align the content with flex properties.

(Since you mentioned that you may need clickable regions, I switched from `li`  to `a` elements.)

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  background: #CCF;
  width: 25em;
}

nav > a {
  flex: auto;  /* flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 1, flex-basis: auto */
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav > a:nth-child(2) {
  background: #CFC;
}

html, body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Sample</a>
  <a href=""><span>span</span></a>
  <a href=""><span>multiple</span> <span>span</span></a>
  <a href="">text <span>span</span></a>
  <a href="">multi<br>line</a>
</nav>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmeVGa)

Note that content placed directly inside a flex container is wrapped in an *anonymous flex item*:

From the spec:

> [**4. Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex
>   container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

So, because the text is automatically wrapped in flex items, you can keep the full height of each item (`align-items: stretch` from the primary container) and vertically center the content (`align-items: center` from the nested containers).

Comment: Thanks! That's close, but the "multiple span" and "text span" items are broken. By changing the `<a>` (or `<li>`) to `display: flex;`, the inline elements (e.g. `<span>`) directly inside it are not rendered inline anymore, but either side-by-side or top-to-bottom (depending on `flex-direction`). This gets way more noticeable if you add several words inside each `<span>`, or add several inline elements.

Answer (score 4):

Make the `li` flex-containers with `flex-direction:column`. I think that's what you are after.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  background: #CCF;
  width: 25em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
ul.first {
  align-items: stretch;
}
ul > li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*outline: 1px dotted #444;*/
}
ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #CFC;
}
```

```html
<ul class="first">
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li><span>span</span>
  </li>
  <li><span>multiple</span>  <span>span</span>
  </li>
  <li>text <span>span</span>
  </li>
  <li>multi
    <br>line</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not what I'm looking for. When you set the `li` element as `display: flex; flex-direction: column`, then the items *multiple span* and *text span* are force-wrapped into two lines, even if there is enough space, instead of remaining in the same line. Remove `width: 25em;` to observe that. (If it helps visualizing, imagine the item contains an icon and a label.)

Answer (score 0):

Flex-child items can also be flex-parent items.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.List {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #CCF;
  width: 25em;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ListItem {
  flex-basis: 5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ListItem:nth-child(2) {
  background: #CFC;
}

.ListItem__content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="List">
  <li class="ListItem">
    <span class="ListItem__content">Sample</span>
  </li>
  <li class="ListItem">
    <span class="ListItem__content">span</span>
  </li>
  <li class="ListItem">
    <span class="ListItem__content">multiple <br> span</span>
  </li>
  <li class="ListItem">
    <span class="ListItem__content">span</span>
  </li>
  <li class="ListItem">
    <span class="ListItem__content">multi<br>line</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are changing/removing items from the markup. For instance, the *multiple span* markup is gone. While in the demo it were two useless `span` tags, they were just a placeholder, as in real world they may be different elements, and we may even have JavaScript manipulating them. You can't remove them.

Comment: Also, your code seems to have added extra stuff (box-sizing, color, classes) that does not contribute in any way to the solution of the stated problem. Such stuff is just noise, making it harder to see your actual solution.

Comment: https://twitter.com/wesbos/status/606129953382408192 Problem is not new. Yes, i wrapped all content from li to span. Because flexbox's children became flex-item elements, and if they was inline, they can get some strange behavior. http://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/KpmKJN - demo. So wrapping content was for prevent some little bugs.