# flexbox - hover not working for flex-item

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am using `flexbox` to control the UI of the button.

When I hover the `Add new` part, the height is not fully covered at all.

[image]

But it works when I hover the expand arrow

[image]

In App.js

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="media">
        <div className="media__bar media__header">
          <div className="media__header__add">
            <div className="media__header__add__new">
              <AddPhotoAlternateIcon fontSize="small" />
              <span>Add new</span>
            </div>
            <button>
              <ExpandMoreIcon style={{ color: "white" }} />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.media {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.media .media__header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.media .media__header .media__header__add {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #c9356e;
  padding: 0.1rem;
}

.media .media__header .media__header__add span {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.media .media__header .media__header__add button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.media .media__header .media__header__add button:hover {
  background-color: #ab235a;
}

.media .media__header .media__header__add .media__header__add__new {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.media .media__header .media__header__add .media__header__add__new:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ab235a;
}
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-pond-6zy5s?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828249/make-flex-items-stretch-full-height-and-vertically-center-their-content

Answer (score 1):

You need to have hover on `.media__header__add` instead of `media__header__add__new` to achieve what you want.

```
.media .media__header .media__header__add .media__header__add__new:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ab235a;
}
```

The above becomes this,

```
.media .media__header .media__header__add:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ab235a;
}
```

Edit: CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-fast-kjtfl

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are putting hover on the individual child tags `(button and div.media__header__add__new)`.

Fot it to work you have to put the hover on the parent element like this.

```
.media .media__header .media__header__add:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ab235a;
}
```

Now you can remove the hover on:

```
.media .media__header .media__header__add .media__header__add__new:hover{}
```

and

```
.media .media__header .media__header__add button:hover {}
```