# Vertical align of text inside flex item didn't work but adding parent properties did the job, why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Plz wait before marking this question as duplicate or possible duplicate.
I  aligned the `child item` vertically centered but the content i.e, text, of that `child item` wasn't aligned at the center of box initially. But when I added `display:flex;`,
`justify-content:center;` & `flex-direction:column;` inside the `child class`, the text was vertically centered.

I checked these questions: 
[How to vertically align text inside a flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311541/how-to-vertically-align-text-inside-a-flexbox) 
[Is there a way to change the vertical-align of items inside flex-items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012030/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-vertical-align-of-items-inside-flex-items)

Some answers helped me to vertically align the `child item` but it wasn't mentioned how to align the contents of `child` at its vertical center at middle.

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-item">hello hello hello hello </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** ***before***

```
.flex-container {
display: flex;    
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-color: lightgrey;
text-align:center;
}

.flex-item {
background-color: cornflowerblue;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

the result is:

[image]

**after adding** `display:flex;`,
`justify-content:center;` & `flex-direction:column;`

**CSS** ***after***

```
 .flex-item {
     background-color: cornflowerblue;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     display:flex;  //<---- added property supposed to be work on parent 
     justify-content:center; //<---- added property supposed to be work on parent
     flex-direction:column;  //<---- added property supposed to be work on parent
```

the result is:

[image]

I want to know if there is some other approach using `flexbox` to align the content of child at vertical center. Also, why adding parent properties i.e, `display:flex;`,
`justify-content:center;` & `flex-direction:column;` worked on `child class`? Aren't these properties supposed to be applied & work only on parents?

Comment: Everything outside a flex container and inside a flex item is rendered as usual.So, this is the reason why you should apply same flex style inside a flex-item. And, I think this is the best solution, I don't think there is a better way to solve that using flex.

Comment: The scope of a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) is limited to a parent/child relationship. Descendants of a flex container beyond the children are not considered part of flex layout and will not accept flex properties. Hence, you will always need to apply `display: flex` (or `display: inline-flex`) to a parent element if you want to apply flex properties to the child. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex items can also be flex containers themselves, which is why you're solution worked. This is because your child item is also the parent item for the text nodes within. However, if you didn't want it to be a flex-container you could also use the property

```
vertical-align: center;
```

On the flex-item instead